# With a Java project in IntelliJ what does the Run command do exactly? Getting different runtime behavior from a ./mvnw command

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am running a Java project based on a maven/pom.xml project. I recently made changes to the code, and am finding that if I run the project using IntelliJ's 'Run' command, the code works as expected, but if I run it using a ./mvnw command I'm seeing different behavior.

The main thing I want to know is exactly what commands are being executed by IntelliJ's run command, so that I can hope to understand exactly what is different. If there is a way to flip a flag in IntelliJ so that it will list exactly the command(s) it is executing, all the better.

As a final detail, here's the 'Run' button:
[image: The run button in IntelliJ]

Comment: Full command should be shown in run output.

Comment: Thanks so much @y.bedrov - that is true, just wasn't obvious because it was truncated weirdly. I fleshed it out an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the command is indeed shown in the output, but it is truncated unless you hover over it. This was unintuitive, and I only noticed when attempting to respond to the comment from @y.bedrov.

Specifically, here's the initial output I see when I 'Run':
[image: Initial output of run]

If I click on that first line, it expands to the full command that is being run:

[image: After clicking the first line of the Run output]